# ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Formatter

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

This seems to be common issue.
I am using `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` to run the tests in IntelliJ Community -IDE(2019.3.4)
I get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:174)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:166)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(PluginFactory.java:206)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:218)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:73)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsParser.parse(RuntimeOptionsParser.java:90)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CommandlineOptionsParser.parse(CommandlineOptionsParser.java:25)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CommandlineOptionsParser.parse(CommandlineOptionsParser.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Formatter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I am using below maven packages:

[image]

[Open Issue](https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/issues/59)

Comment: Have you tried [solutions](https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/issues/59#issuecomment-421634317) from that thread?

Comment: @Andrey I just tried that then I got this error `Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:179)` I am using `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` in `cucumber-core-4.7.2` to run in IDE

Comment: @SMPH Updating the intellij to latest version could fix this... The cucumber version u r using no longer support the Formatter interfaces for plugins.

Comment: @Grasshopper I updated intellij community to latest `2019.3.5 (Build#193.7288.26)`. Even `cucumber-core 5.7.0`, No luck though